# Why should I send token in `Authorization: Bearer ` header?

Tags: api, security, authentication, authorization, jwt

I am new to API development. Currently I pass my access/auth token in request body. For eaxmple,

```
{
status:true,
token:"<thetoken>"
}
```

But, When I refer about API security, They use `Authorization` header to pass the token.

My question is, What will happen or Whats wrong, If I send token in request body?

-- Thank you ❤  ---

Comment: This is common practice with authorization methods like OAuth. The API can authorize the request before accepting the contents. This can save some processing overhead by not accepting request that have not been validated by their headers.

Are you writing your own API?

Comment: @tshimkus Yes I am writing own API

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, securing API endpoints is a solved task. Instead of inventing your own authorization protocol, I suggest you to have a look at already existing industry standards like the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework ([RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)).

Following standards makes sense for multiple reasons:

- they are widely known and battle tested
- reference implementations and libs are available
- you can stand on the shoulders of giants and focus on your business logic
- etc.

However, there is nothing wrong with sending an access token in a request body. In [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) the OAuth 2.0 protocol defines all possible bearer token usages including sending the token as a [Form-Encoded Body Parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.2). Make sure to read carefully and take the security considerations into account.

Long story short: It does not really matter how you hand around access token, as long as you follow the standards.

Comment: if i pass tokens to thee header does that mean they are gonna be attached to the headers for subsequent request and response i make.